# VC неадекватно переносит строки

Tags: visual-studio

При использовании таких плагинов как Beautify css/sass/scss/less или Beautify, в обычном тексте вставляются невидимые разрывы строк, которые можно увидеть только в ворде, или по факту в браузере я получаю тег br, там где его быть не должно.
Раньше такого не было, возможно это с обновлениями vc пришло.
Понять на словах что происходит довольно тяжело, прикрепляю видео.
https://yadi.sk/i/SAWwj8XmH1xfng
Может это и нормально с какой то точки зрения, скажете вы, но работать так не возможно.
Кто то сталкивался с подобным? т.е. по сути нужно что бы разрывы не вставлялись.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. html.format.wrapLineLength = 0